# Javascript multiple "try"s

Tags: javascript, function, try-catch, expression, metaprogramming

We all know the basic escaping mechanism in JS:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch(err) {
    ..
}
```

I have a JSON data in which I want to check if a lead has a full name. If not, try to compose one with first and last name fields (I actually hard code a space there which is a problem as well.) and finally if all fails show "No Name".

Or in pseudo code:

```
try {
    name = lead['Details']['Name']['Full'];
} else try {
    name = lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
} catch (e) {
    name = "No Name";
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"Any suggestions?"_ yes, use conditional logic instead, ie `if`

Comment: @Phil, I also cannot for sure tell I will have 'Details', or 'Name' so I will end up with many ifs. I am looking for a method similar to Rails' "dig"

Comment: If only JS had null conditional operators :( Although I guess [Stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) is better than nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest your second try/catch block in the exception block of the first try/catch block as follows:

```
try {
    name = lead['Details']['Name']['Full'];
} catch(ex0) {      
  try {
      name = lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
  } catch (ex1) {
      name = "No Name";
  }
}
```

This is valid syntax, and functionally equivalent to what you're requiring

Comment: That'll work. Not the most beautiful function I ever saw, but there seems to be no other solution. I had to run a try/catch on lead['Details']['Name'] since it may be empty. What if lead['Details']['Name']['First'] is empty but not lead['Details']['Name']['Last'] ? are we going to get a full name or will it go to the catch? I think another failsafe may be needed there. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that 2 years later, but with support of Babeljs even before, the best fitting solution should be based on [*Optional chaining*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), this Q remains a perfect target for practicing entirely function based approaches.

Implementing e.g. an [`afterThrowing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662004/equivalent-of-try-catch-as-an-expression/63662812#63662812) [***method modifier***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600780/ts-js-overwrite-a-function-and-call-original-function-within/63625453#63625453) could result in an expression as short and as close as to the OP's pseudo code ...

```
try {
  name = lead['Meta']['Name']['Full'];
} else try {
  name = lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
} catch (e) {
  name = 'No Name';
}
```

... then would turn into something like ...

```
function getFullName(lead) {
  return lead['Meta']['Name']['Full'];
}
function getComposedFullName(lead) {
  return lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
}

const name = (getFullName.afterThrowing((error, [data] = args) =>

  (getComposedFullName.afterThrowing((/*error,[data]=args*/) => 'No Name')(data))

)(lead));
```

... implementation and example code as proof of concept ...

```js
const leadTestSample = {
  success: {
    fullName: {
      Meta: {
        Name: {
          Full: "Mary Jane Doe"
        }
      }
    },
    composed: {
      Details: {
        Name: {
          First: "Jane",
          Last: "Doe"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  failure: {
    Meta: {},
    Details: {}
  }
};


function getFullName(lead) {
  return lead['Meta']['Name']['Full'];
}
function getComposedFullName(lead) {
  return lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
}
const nameDefault = 'No Name';


/*
try {
  name = lead['Meta']['Name']['Full'];
} else try {
  name = lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];
} catch (e) {
  name = 'No Name';
}
*/

const fullNameData = leadTestSample.success.fullName;
const composedData = leadTestSample.success.composed;
const failureData = leadTestSample.failure;

console.log(
  (getFullName.afterThrowing((error, [data] = args) =>

    (getComposedFullName.afterThrowing(() => nameDefault)(data))

  )(fullNameData))
);
console.log(
  (getFullName.afterThrowing((error, [data] = args) =>

    (getComposedFullName.afterThrowing(() => nameDefault)(data))

  )(composedData))
);
console.log(
  (getFullName.afterThrowing((error, [data] = args) =>

    (getComposedFullName.afterThrowing(() => nameDefault)(data))

  )(failureData))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  (function (Function) {

    const fctPrototype = Function.prototype;
    const FUNCTION_TYPE = (typeof Function);

    function isFunction(type) {
      return (
           (typeof type == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.call == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.apply == FUNCTION_TYPE)
      );
    }
    function getSanitizedTarget(target) {
      return ((target != null) && target) || null;
    }

    function afterThrowing/*Modifier*/(handler, target) {
      target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

      const proceed = this;
      return (

        isFunction(handler) &&
        isFunction(proceed) &&

        function () {
          const context = target || getSanitizedTarget(this);
          const args = arguments;

          let result;
          try {
            result = proceed.apply(context, args);

          } catch (exception) {

            result = handler.call(context, exception, args);
          }
          return result;
        }

      ) || proceed;
    }
    // afterThrowing.toString = () => 'afterThrowing() { [native code] }';

    Object.defineProperty(fctPrototype, 'afterThrowing', {
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: afterThrowing/*Modifier*/
    });

  }(Function));
</script>
```

I wouldn't mind if, at one day, JavaScript officially features ... `Function.prototype[`[`before`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/37bf42a6fc0b7f9549b8#file-function-before-js)`|`[`after`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/21677f85aa598d262c66#file-function-after-js)`|`[`around`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/895cd9eb04239e10e8eb#file-function-around-js)`|`[`afterThrowing`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/9ddf5ce515f1344c84bd#file-function-afterthrowing-js)`|`[`afterFinally`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/3b31cd5e63d43b9e7c4e#file-function-afterfinally-js)`]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of do this in using one try-catch block only. As we know when we will get type error in javascript when access something that does not exist.

> See the below code  snippet.

```
function getName(isFullName='true'){

  try{
     if(isFullName)
       name = lead['Details']['Name']['Full'];       
     else
       name = lead['Details']['Name']['First'] + " " + lead['Details']['Name']['Last'];       
     }
   catch(e){
     if (e instanceof TypeError && isFullName) 
         getName(false);
     name = 'No name';   
    }
}
```

In case name is full name is coming undefined then, we need to add an extra if block to check for the undefined case.