# Equivalent of try...catch as an expression

Tags: javascript, function, try-catch, expression, metaprogramming

Im looking for a way to do something like:

```
myVar = try {someFunction();} catch (e) {return undefined;} ?? defaultValue;
```

Which I know isn't correct but you get the idea. I just wondered if there was an elegant way to do this?

Comment: There is none. You can use an IIFE if you must. There's also a (not yet official) [proposal](https://github.com/isiahmeadows/proposal-try-expression).

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do currently is probably an IIFE:

```
myVar = (() => {
  try {
    return someFunction();
  } catch (e) {
  }
})() ?? defaultValue;
```

Comment: What's the returned value in the case of an exception?

Comment: In that case, nothing is returned, so it defaults to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing e.g. an [`afterThrowing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959181/javascript-multiple-trys/63678786#63678786) [***method modifier***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600780/ts-js-overwrite-a-function-and-call-original-function-within/63625453#63625453) could result in an expression as short and as close as to the OP's pseudo code ...

```
const value = try {someFunction();} catch (e) {return undefined;} ?? defaultValue;
```

... then would turn into something like ...

```
const value = (someFunction.afterThrowing(() => null)()) ?? defaultValue;
```

... implementation and example code as proof of concept ...

```js
// myVar = try {someFunction();} catch (e) {return undefined;} ?? defaultValue;

function throwError() {
  throw (new Error('invocation failure'));
}
function getDate() {
  return Date.now();
}
const defaultValue = '... did throw.'

// expressions as short and as close as one can get
// to what has been ask for ...
//
console.log(
  (getDate.afterThrowing(() => null)()) ?? defaultValue
);
console.log(
  (throwError.afterThrowing(() => null)()) ?? defaultValue
);


// demonstrate capability of the after throwing handler ...
function afterThrowingHandler(error, args) {
  console.log(
    'afterThrowingHandler :: context, error, argsList :',
    this,
    error.toString(),
    Array.from(args)
  );
  return null; // according to the OP's use case.
}

console.log(
  (getDate.afterThrowing(afterThrowingHandler)()) ?? defaultValue
);

console.log(
  (throwError.afterThrowing(

    afterThrowingHandler,
    { biz: 'buzz' }

  )('foo', 'bar', 'baz')) ?? defaultValue
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  (function (Function) {

    const fctPrototype = Function.prototype;
    const FUNCTION_TYPE = (typeof Function);

    function isFunction(type) {
      return (
           (typeof type == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.call == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.apply == FUNCTION_TYPE)
      );
    }
    function getSanitizedTarget(target) {
      return ((target != null) && target) || null;
    }

    function afterThrowing/*Modifier*/(handler, target) {
      target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

      const proceed = this;
      return (

        isFunction(handler) &&
        isFunction(proceed) &&

        function () {
          const context = target || getSanitizedTarget(this);
          const args = arguments;

          let result;
          try {
            result = proceed.apply(context, args);

          } catch (exception) {

            result = handler.call(context, exception, args);
          }
          return result;
        }

      ) || proceed;
    }
    // afterThrowing.toString = () => 'afterThrowing() { [native code] }';

    Object.defineProperty(fctPrototype, 'afterThrowing', {
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: afterThrowing/*Modifier*/
    });

  }(Function));
</script>
```

I wouldn't mind if, at one day, JavaScript officially features ... `Function.prototype[`[`before`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/37bf42a6fc0b7f9549b8#file-function-before-js)`|`[`after`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/21677f85aa598d262c66#file-function-after-js)`|`[`around`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/895cd9eb04239e10e8eb#file-function-around-js)`|`[`afterThrowing`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/9ddf5ce515f1344c84bd#file-function-afterthrowing-js)`|`[`afterFinally`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/3b31cd5e63d43b9e7c4e#file-function-afterfinally-js)`]`.

Answer (score -1):

Functional try catch

```
const tryF = (func) => {
  try {
    return func();
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Then to use

```
Const val = tryF(() => dosomething ())
```