# TS / JS: Overwrite a function and call original function within

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, metaprogramming, modifier

I'd like to know if there's a way to modify a function in TypeScript and access the original function within. This is an example of how I got it to work:

```
let obj = {
  shout: () => {
    console.log("AHHHHH!");
  },
};

let s = obj.shout;

obj.shout = () => {
  console.log("I'm going to shout.");
  s();
};

obj.shout(); //-> "I'm going to shout", "AHHHHH!"
```

This way I was able to add a warning to my shout function whenever it's called - but I feel like that's an ugly way to do it, so I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: `s.call(obj)` or `s.apply(obj)`, potentially

Comment: Normally you'd also care about passing the right receiver (`this`) and all arguments to the function and to `return` its return value, but if you know that you don't need them (in your case, an arrow function with no parameters and no return value) then this totally works. This is the normal approach.

Comment: What you are looking for could be referred to as *method modification*, and your first approach is as pure as can be. Taking *Bergi*'s remarks into account, one  could think about providing some abstractions in order to cover the most useful cases of intercepting and altering a method's control flow (thus modifying a function/method) which is done exemplarily within my beneath answer.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's approach is the most intuitive/natural one. With JavaScript applications one sometimes is in need of ***intercepting*** and/or ***modifying*** the ***control flow*** of functionality one does not own or is, for other reasons, not allowed to touch.

For exactly this scenario there is no other way than to preserve and alter such logic by wrapping their original implementation. This ability is not unique to JavaScript. There is quite a history of programming languages that enable ***Metaprogramming*** via ***Reflection*** and ***Self-Modification***.

Of cause one could/should provide bulletproof but handy abstractions for all the possibly modifier use cases that one can think of ... starting right away with the OP's use case that is the most obvious and easiest to implement one, which could be handled by e.g a ***before*** modifier ...

```js
const obj = {
  shout: function (...args) {

    console.log('AHHHHH!');

    console.log('args : ', args);
    console.log('this is me : ', this);
  }
};
obj.shout();


obj.shout = obj.shout.before(function () {

  console.log("I'm going to shout.");

}, obj);

obj.shout('test of "before" modifier');


const anotherOne = {
  name: 'anotherOne'
};
obj.shout.call(anotherOne, 'delegation and self reflection');


/*
console.log(
  'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype) :',
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype)
);
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  (function (Function) {

    const fctPrototype = Function.prototype;
    const FUNCTION_TYPE = (typeof Function);

    function isFunction(type) {
      return (
           (typeof type == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.call == FUNCTION_TYPE)
        && (typeof type.apply == FUNCTION_TYPE)
      );
    }
    function getSanitizedTarget(target) {
      return ((target != null) && target) || null;
    }

    function before/*Modifier*/(handler, target) {
      target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

      const proceed = this;
      return (

        isFunction(handler) &&
        isFunction(proceed) &&

        function () {
          const context = target || getSanitizedTarget(this);
          const args = arguments;

        //handler.apply(context, args);
          handler.call(context, args);

          return proceed.apply(context, args);
        }

      ) || proceed;
    }
    // before.toString = () => 'before() { [native code] }';

    Object.defineProperty(fctPrototype, 'before', {
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: before/*Modifier*/ 
    });

  }(Function));
</script>
```

As one can see from the example code, which uses the additionally provided implementation, `Function.prototype` is quite comfortable for enabling ***method modifiers* in JavaScript**.

But regardless of how/where one does implement such modifier functionality, following applies to any reliable modifier code (*Bergi* already did point to it) ...

1. The modifier has to support a `target` object (for delegating the correct `this` context, if needed).
2. The modifier has to either correctly forward a wrapped method's arguments or handle its return value respectively the exception of its failing invocation.

I wouldn't mind if, at one day, JavaScript officially features ... `Function.prototype[`[`before`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/37bf42a6fc0b7f9549b8#file-function-before-js)`|`[`after`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/21677f85aa598d262c66#file-function-after-js)`|`[`around`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/895cd9eb04239e10e8eb#file-function-around-js)`|`[`afterThrowing`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/9ddf5ce515f1344c84bd#file-function-afterthrowing-js)`|`[`afterFinally`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/3b31cd5e63d43b9e7c4e#file-function-afterfinally-js)`]`.

Comment: ... and the uncommented -1 vote ("This answer is not useful") was earned due to which specific technical reason/flaw?

Answer (score -1):

When you assign a new function to an existing object that like you lose the reference to the old value.

But if you use classes, you do have have access to overloaded methods via `super`.

```
class ObjA {
    shout() {
        console.log('AHHHHH!')
    }
}

class ObjB extends ObjA {
    shout() {
        super.shout()
        console.log("I'm going to shout.")
    }
}

const obj = new ObjB()
obj.shout() //-> "I'm going to shout", "AHHHHH!"
```