# Is there a design pattern in JavaScript for writing functions that can conditionally throw an exception or capture it to return a value?

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns, try-catch, control-flow

Sometimes there is a need to call a function and handle the exception directly (with a try/catch), and other times there it is preferable to call *the same* function and receive a `null` or `false` if it would otherwise fail.

This idea or use-case is similar to Rails in ActiveRecord where you have a choice of calling `User.find(1)` or `User.find!(1)` — the former will return `nil` if not found and the latter will raise an exception.

**Question:** I am the author of these functions so I can design this in any way. Is there a prescribed pattern in javascript for this idea?

---

One idea is to just mimic what is done in ActiveRecord:

```js
// returns API data or bubbles-up exception
function getDataFromAPI() {
  const response = callApi(); // function throws error if not 200
  return response.data;
}

// returns API data or null
function getDataFromAPI_() {
  try {
    return getDataFromAPI();
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Maybe another way is to create a generic wrapper for the try/catch, though this example doesn't account for arguments:

```js
// returns API data, but will raise an exception if
// `response` has no `data` property...
function getDataFromAPI() {
  const response = callApi();
  return response.data;
}

// return function or null
function nullIfError(func) {
  try {
    return func();
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}

nullIfError(getDataFromAPI)
```

Or, add a parameter to conditially change it the behavior, but I don't like that it's always wrapped in a try/catch...

```js
function getDataFromAPI(throwError = true) {
  try {
    const response = callApi();
    return response.data;
  } catch(e) {
    if (throwError) throw(e);
    else return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: the error in your first example is down to poor handling of a possibly undefined value, not an error thrown from the API call itself so it would be more appropriate to accommodate that properly in the return ie. with optional chaining `return response?.data ?? null`

Comment: Your second example can be adapted to work with arguments either by doing `nullIfError(() => getDataFromAPI(arg1, arg2))` or using `Function.prototype.bind` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: @pilchard I realize now that accessing a property on an object doesn't throw an exception. I've updated the example to better match my specific case, where calling the function will throw an error if the HTTP response is not 200.

Comment: @JimNilsson Sorry, didn't mean to focus on the lack of arguments. I can get that to work, but more interested in the design pattern overal—is there a typical design pattern in JS that covers this idea?

Comment: "*call the same function*" - no. You want to do different things, you call different functions.

Comment: @burn ... Regarding the late provided sole answer, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no real established pattern, one could introduce prototypal and/or non-prototypal implementations of possibly desirable function/method-modifiers (such as `afterFinally`, `afterThrowing`, `after`, `before`, `around`) which allow the interception, introspection and manipulation of a function's/method's control flow in terms of its arguments, return value and context at such a modified function's/method's call/apply/execution time.

As for the OP's use case the [`afterThrowing` modifier](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/afterThrowing/index.js) comes in very handy.

The next provided example code shows both its implementation and usage.

```js
function deliverData() {
  return { data: { foo: "bar "} };
}
function throwError() {
  throw new Error('API not available.');
}

function callMockedApi() {
  return [deliverData, throwError][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]();
}

function getDataFromAPI() {
  const response = callMockedApi();
  return response.data;
}
const getDataFromAPI_ = getDataFromAPI.afterThrowing(() => null);

console.log(getDataFromAPI_());
console.log(getDataFromAPI());
```

```html
<script>
function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    'function' === typeof value &&
    'function' === typeof value.call &&
    'function' === typeof value.apply
  );
}
function getSanitizedTarget(value) {
  return value ?? null;
}

function afterThrowing(handler, target) {
  target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

  const proceed = this;
  return (
    isFunction(handler) &&
    isFunction(proceed) &&

    function afterThrowingType(...argumentArray) {
      const context = getSanitizedTarget(this) ?? target;

      let result;
      try {
        result = proceed.apply(context, argumentArray);
      } catch (exception) {
        result = handler.call(context, exception, argumentArray);
      }
      return result;
    }
  ) || proceed;
}

Reflect.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'afterThrowing', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: afterThrowing,
});
</script>
```

More on this subject can be read up at ...

- [*Javascript multiple "try"s*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678786/2627243)
- [*How to use common try-catch for processing every given function in Javascript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690100/2627243)
- [*TS / JS: Overwrite a function and call original function within*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625453/2627243)
- [*How does one elegantly provide try-catch functionality to functions and methods which are listed within an array and are about to be executed/invoked?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69728758/2627243)